# Python curses how to change cursor position with curses.setsyx(y,x)?

Tags: python, python-3.x, curses

I am learning how to use curses and I am trying to create a simple program to start off. I am expecting this program to have a q printed in the top left corner always, then it prints the most recently pressed character in 1,1. But I'm not sure how to set the position of the cursor, which should be changed by using the curses.setsyx(y,x) function but it isn't working. Here is my program:

```
import curses
import sys,os

def screen_init(stdscr):
    stdscr.clear()
    stdscr.refresh()
    stdscr.scrollok(1)

    height, width = stdscr.getmaxyx()

    curses.start_color()
    curses.init_pair(1, curses.COLOR_CYAN, curses.COLOR_BLACK)

    while True:
            stdscr.addstr(0, 0, "q", curses.color_pair(1))
            key = stdscr.getch()
            stdscr.addstr(1, 1, chr(int(key)), curses.color_pair(1))
            if key == ord('q'):
                    break
            elif key == ord('p'):
                    curses.setsyx(3, 3)
                    curs_y, curs_x = curses.getsyx()
                    curses.doupdate()
                    stdscr.addstr(1, 1, "clicked! " + str(curs_x) + " " + 
str(curs_y), curses.color_pair(1))

    stdscr.refresh()
    curses.endwin()

def main():
    curses.wrapper(screen_init)

if (__name__ == "__main__"):
    main();
```

Any ideas on why it isn't doing anything? When I use getsyx() it gets 3, 3 but the cursor's true position doesn't change

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`setsyx` and `getsyx` affect a special workspace-screen named **`newscr`**, which is used to construct changes sent to **`stdscr`** when you call **`refresh`**.

**`stdscr`** has its **own** position, which is not affected by those calls.

Comment: Ah ok, I understand! But even when i call refresh() both before and after doupdate, it doesn't change the position of the cursor, is there something else that I have to do?

Comment: no... you should be using **`wmove`** to get the cursor to move around on the screen.

Comment: Oh, wait I misunderstood what you said, ok got it, thanks!

Answer (score 6):

you can use `stdscr.getyx()` and `stdscr.move(y, x)` instead.

Answer (score 0):

**stdscr.move(y, x)** moves the **stdscr**’s cursor, which is used for output position of characters. (so you should use this one)

**curses.setsyx(y,x)** moves the **newscr**'s cursor which is used for show the cursor on the screen.

How to use setsyx():

```
for i in range(10):
    # output i
    stdscr.addstr(f"{i} ")
    # refresh stdscr to newscr(not show on the screen)
    stdscr.noutrefresh()
    # move the cursor of newscr to (1,0)
    curses.setsyx(1,0)
    # show it 
    curses.doupdate()
    time.sleep(1)
    
stdscr.getch()
```

You will see the Number showed one by one, but the cursor always show at (1,0)

[image]

The normal refresh() call is simply noutrefresh() followed by doupdate(); but we need setsyx() in the middle, so call them separately.